# Is this the proper return of a serialized JSON object?

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to serialize my Entity model to JSON and I'm not sure if the return is correct.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    using (var MGC = new GC_BranchNameEntities())
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var jsonIDSA = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MGC.INV_LIVE_IDSA, Formatting.None);
        try
        {
            return Ok(jsonIDSA);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest("Error occured when retreiving IDSA data " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what it return:

> `"[{\"id\":1,\"barcode\":\"TestBARCODE\",\"nsr\":0,\"stk_in\":0,\"stk_out\":0,\"sales\":0,\"balance\":1},{\"id\":2,\"barcode\":\"TestBARCODE2\",\"nsr\":0,\"stk_in\":0,\"stk_out\":0,\"sales\":0,\"balance\":1},{\"id\":3,\"barcode\":\"TestBARCODE3\",\"nsr\":0,\"stk_in\":0,\"stk_out\":0,\"sales\":0,\"balance\":1},{\"id\":4,\"barcode\":\"AAA\",\"nsr\":0,\"stk_in\":0,\"stk_out\":0,\"sales\":0,\"balance\":1},{\"id\":5,\"barcode\":\"BBB\",\"nsr\":0,\"stk_in\":0,\"stk_out\":0,\"sales\":0,\"balance\":1}]"`

. I wasn't expecting a string with \ escapes. I am about to deserialize this in another project to use the values.

I was looking for something like this

> [
>     {'id':1,'barcode':'TestBARCODE','nsr':0,'stk_in':0,'stk_out':0,'sales':0,'balance':1},
>     {'id':2,'barcode':'TestBARCODE2','nsr':0,'stk_in':0,'stk_out':0,'sales':0,'balance':1},
>     {'id':3,'barcode':'TestBARCODE3','nsr':0,'stk_in':0,'stk_out':0,'sales':0,'balance':1},
>     {'id':4,'barcode':'AAA','nsr':0,'stk_in':0,'stk_out':0,'sales':0,'balance':1},
>     {'id':5,'barcode':'BBB','nsr':0,'stk_in':0,'stk_out':0,'sales':0,'balance':1}
>   ]

Comment: If you're debugging the project with Visual Studio, it's just the debugger view that shows the quotation marks escaped.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct! The backslashes are just used for escaping and this json should work fine.